# Convertir un arreglo de Enteros a un arreglo de Caracteres con formato hexadecimal

Tags: c++

Quiero convertir un arreglo de enteros a un arreglo de caracteres formateando los enteros en hexadecimal, a continuación dejo un ejemplo de como lo hago actualmente, sin embargo, me gustaría una forma mas fácil de hacerlo con sprintf, esto debido a que cuando sean muchos valores en vez de dos la función sprintf quedaría muy larga y poco optimizada:

```
int int_array[2];
char char_array[2];
unsigned char uchar_array1[2];
unsigned char uchar_array2[2];

uchar_array1[0] = 0x31;
uchar_array1[1] = 0x32;

uchar_array2[0] = 0x33;
uchar_array2[1] = 0x34;

int_array[0] = uchar_array1[0] ^ uchar_array2[0]; //Funcion XOR
int_array[1] = uchar_array1[1] ^ uchar_array2[1]; //Funcion XOR

sprintf(char_array, "%02X%02X", int_array[0], int_array[1]); //Función a Mejorar
```

Intenté hacer esto:

```
for(int aux = 0; aux < 2; aux++)
{
    sprintf(char_array[aux], "%02X", int_array[aux]);
}
```

Pero me manda el siguiente error:

```
argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Me gustaría una forma más fácil de hacerlo con `sprintf`.

Pues olvida la idea, `sprintf` pertenece a las funciones de escritura en consola de C, en C++ se usan los objetos *stream* como [`std::cout` [image]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), además la manera de trabajar con cadenas de caracteres en C++ es usando objetos de tipo [`std::string` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) no con formaciones<sup>1</sup> de caracteres.

#### Propuesta.

Utiliza un [*stream* de texto [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int valores[]{250, 186, 218};
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.width(2);
    ss.fill('0');

    for (int valor : valores)
        ss << std::hex << valor;

    std::cout << ss.str();

    return 0;
}
```

[El código anterior](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XCytFI3zMzZP3dxg) muestra la cadena hexadecimal `fabada`, está utilizando el manipulador [`std::hex` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) para pasar a hexadecimal los datos enteros recibidos y guardarlos en un *stream* de texto; al *stream* resultante se le puede pedir su contenido actual como cadena mediante la función [`str` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str).

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 2):

Tu programa tiene varios problemas:

- La representación de cada caracter ocupa dos caracteres, luego para almacenar la representación de 2 caracteres necesitas un buffer **mínimo** de 5 caracteres... y tu estás usando uno de 2. Estás pisando memoria que pertenece a otras variables y eso va a provocar antes o después comportamientos erráticos en la aplicación.
- Sería conveniente usar `std::string` antes que `char*`. `char*` es trabajar a muy bajo nivel y hay que tener mucho cuidado en todo momento... `std::string` te permite abstraerte de algunos problemas.
- El error es lógico, `sprintf` espera un puntero a `char` como primer parámetro y tu le estás pasando un `char`.

Tu código, corregido, podría quedar así:

```
int int_array[2];
char char_array[5]; // <<--- Se incrementa el tamaño del buffer
unsigned char uchar_array1[2];
unsigned char uchar_array2[2];

uchar_array1[0] = 0x31;
uchar_array1[1] = 0x32;

uchar_array2[0] = 0x33;
uchar_array2[1] = 0x34;

int_array[0] = uchar_array1[0] ^ uchar_array2[0]; //Funcion XOR
int_array[1] = uchar_array1[1] ^ uchar_array2[1]; //Funcion XOR

for(int aux = 0; aux < 2; aux++)
{
  sprintf(&char_array[aux*2], "%02X", int_array[aux]);
  //      ^ Se le pasa una referencia (aqui puntero) al caracter que nos interesa
}
```